# How can I be notified on any push, for all of the repositories of multiple organizations in GitHub?

Tags: github

For a period of time I need to monitor and code-review every push that happens for **ALL** of the repositories of multiple organizations on GitHub.

For example:

```
/Org1/Repo1
/Org1/Repo2
/Org1/Repo3
...
/Org1/Repo15

/Org2/Repo1
/Org2/Repo2
...
/Org2/Repo10
```

I tried the [Notifications](https://github.com/settings/notifications) and watched those repos so that they are on my [Watched repos](https://github.com/watching). I chagned the **subscriptions** => **watching** to **Notify me: on GitHub**. But when a colleague pushed a new code, nothing happened. And as more pushes are done, I get no notifications at all. Not even one notification.

So, how can I achieve that goal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this by setting up a `webhook` for push events in each repository. GitHub's webhooks allow you to build or set up integrations which subscribe to certain events on GitHub.com. When one of those events is triggered, GitHub sends a `HTTP POST payload` to the webhook configured URL. Webhooks can be used to update an external issue tracker, trigger CI builds, update a backup mirror or even deploy to your production server.

webhook will now fire every time there is a push to the repository, sending a POST request to the server URL you specified. You could have this server send you an email or another form of notification when it receives a payload. Keep in mind that you will have to handle the payload sent to your server and turn it into a useful notification for yourself.

Here is how you can set up a webhook for push events, in the repository,

- Go to the `"Settings"` tab. Click on `"Webhooks"`.
- Click on `"Add webhook"`. Enter the URL for your server in the `"Payload URL"` box.
- Choose `"application/json"` for the content type.
- Select `"Just the push event."` option. Make sure "Active" is checked.
- Click `"Add webhook"` to save the changes

Webhook will now fire every time there is a push to the repository, sending a POST request to the server URL you specified. You could have this server send you an email or another form of notification when it receives a payload. Keep in mind that you will have to handle the payload sent to your server and turn it into a useful notification for yourself.

Unfortunately, this must be done for each individual repository you want to monitor. If you need to do this for many repositories, you might find it useful to use GitHub's API to automate the process.

It would look like something below in Python using [PyGithub](https://github.com/PyGithub/PyGithub),

```
from github import Github

g = Github("access_token")

for org in ["Org1", "Org2"]:
    for repo in g.get_organization(org).get_repos():
        config = {"url": "https://your-server.com/payload", "content_type": "json"}
        events = ["push"]
        repo.create_hook("web", config, events, active=True)
```

Above script will iterate over all the repositories in the specified organizations and create a webhook for push events.

You need to replace `"access_token"` with your actual access token and `https://your-server.com/payload` with your actual server URL.

Comment: Thank you for this answer. I knew about webhooks. It requires a lot of extra work. Notifications are easy. No need for a server (a hook) to setup, even if you go for serverless code you still need to code a hook and make it work for you. Also I don't want my inbox to become dirty. I want to use GitHub's internal inbox (notifications). But I'm grateful for yoru detailed answer. Thank you.